# Can't run my app on openshift 503 error

Tags: java, tomcat, openshift

I have a simple servlet application. I created war file and tried it on my local server - everything goes well. 
Then I decided to publish it on openshift servers.

Here is the link http://asciiart-pbweb.rhcloud.com/
I renamed my war file to ROOT.war following these instructions

https://developers.openshift.com/servers/tomcat/deployment-options.html
and pushed all stuff to the server.

But now it comes like 503 error. I can't figure out what's wrong.

I entered this command

```
 rhc tail asciiart
```

and the full output of that

```
==> app-root/logs/haproxy_ctld.log <==
I, [2016-05-18T04:11:59.618001 #461900]  INFO -- : Starting haproxy_ctld
I, [2016-05-18T04:26:53.602679 #520318]  INFO -- : Starting haproxy_ctld

==> app-root/logs/haproxy.log <==
[ALERT] 138/042302 (466052) : proxy 'express' has no server available!
[WARNING] 138/042653 (466052) : Server express/local-gear is DOWN for maintenance.
[WARNING] 138/042653 (520304) : config : log format ignored for proxy 'stats' since it has no log address.
[WARNING] 138/042653 (520304) : config : log format ignored for proxy 'express' since it has no log address.
[WARNING] 138/042653 (520304) : Server express/local-gear is DOWN, reason: Layer7 wrong status, code: 500, info: "HTTP status check returned code <3C>500<3E>", check duration: 3ms. 0 active and 0 backup servers left. 0 sessions active, 0 requeued, 0 remaining in queue.
[ALERT] 138/042653 (520304) : proxy 'express' has no server available!
[WARNING] 138/042654 (520304) : Server express/local-gear is DOWN for maintenance.
[WARNING] 138/042718 (520304) : Server express/local-gear is UP (leaving maintenance).
[WARNING] 138/042719 (520304) : Server express/local-gear is DOWN, reason: Layer7 wrong status, code: 500, info: "HTTP status check returned code <3C>500<3E>", check duration: 8ms. 0 active and 0 backup servers left. 0 sessions active, 0 requeued, 0 remaining in queue.
[ALERT] 138/042719 (520304) : proxy 'express' has no server available!

==> app-root/logs/jbossews.log <==
May 18, 2016 4:27:16 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService start
INFO: Starting service Catalina
May 18, 2016 4:27:16 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine start
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/6.0.41
May 18, 2016 4:27:16 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
INFO: Deploying web application archive ROOT.war
May 18, 2016 4:27:17 AM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol start
INFO: Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-127.6.11.129-8080
May 18, 2016 4:27:17 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 997 ms
```

Comment: Share more logs.sometimes due to RAM space issues we tend to get this kind of errors.

Comment: Some time this may occurs as the file is not properly deployed on the server.
Do re-check your steps to deploy as instructed in the link : https://developers.openshift.com/servers/tomcat/deployment-options.html

Comment: Dear friends. I added log outputs. Please if you have any idea how to solve it tell me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now the DNS entry is gone, so my best guess would be that you did not have anything listening/responding to the root context of your application (/), so the proxy server sees the gear as being down.  Make sure you have a least an index page or something that should load when you visit the root context.

Comment: Dear friend. I made another app - here is the link http://imagefromtext-pbweb.rhcloud.com/    On my local tomcat6 this works fine. But here it's says 404 error(Controller class doesn't exist.)

Comment: One more question:  when I create ROOT.war file and upload that on to openshift server, then restart project - it doesn't "unpack" my war file - it just copies that file to another directory. Is it normal?

Comment: What server are you using and what directory are you putting your ROOT.war file in?

Comment: sorry long time no answer. Finally I decided not use war files. But develop via openshift eclipse plugin - it's much easier to configure the whole stuff. The tutorial is on the link - https://blog.openshift.com/day-28-openshift-eclipse-integration-for-java-developers/

Comment: and actually war files are also there... But it's much more easier and fun